# SSD can't be formatted

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive, formatting, usb-storage, repair

I'm trying to get a fake 7TB SSd storage, that in reality is a 64GB SSD to work. I can work on a Linux machine as well.

Until now, the disk is not formatable, I can't clean it using diskpart on Windows 10. Can't assign a volumen to it.
Tried following this tut:
https://www.diskpart.com/articles/ssd-will-not-format-0310.html

How would I proceed?

Comment: Your best option is to return it and get your money back. Second best is to throw it in the garbage.

Comment: The problem is that there are many ways to fake drive capacity and the "how" of fixing it depends entirely on what the type of drive is and what was done to it. Make and model could come in to play as if the firmware were rewritten then you would have to know who the original manufacturer was and hope that they release a firmware for that model and hope that the firmware writing tool can actually flash it. The amount of intimate knowledge about the drive and the methods of faking, writing and then undoing is not worth it for one item you can write off as a learning experience.

Comment: I'm trying to run f3probe on Linux. It's taking forever, but I'll leave it going.

Comment: So, I used the f3probe on Linux, but having waited a few hours, I am now chucking the insides of his thing away. I'll leave the casing for my next purchase. GL everyone.